# How to set default permissions of files uploaded through Joomla Media Manager?

Tags: file-upload, media-manager, file-permissions

I'm running Joomla(`3.9.8`) on an Apache/PHP server on Linux.

If you touch a file as the server user (and from PHP running on the server), the permissions of that file are: `-rw-rw-r--`.

However, if a file is uploaded via the Media Manager (and JCE File Browser), the permissions look like this: `-rw-r--r--`. The server thread has `Umask: 0022`.

Where is `g+w` lost and more importantly is there a setting to add `g+w` for uploads (or set permissions for uploads in general)?

I could overwrite with `inotify cron`, but that would be the last resort.